# Regex to check string formatting?

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to match a string formatted like this:

```
2014-08-06T21:02:16Z,-33.7939310,151.0553090,-0.8
```

Do I have to use `//d` for each individual digit? what about the negative numbers?

Comment: If your goal is to parse the string, you probably would be better off calling [split(",")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), then passing the first element of the split to [DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime-java.lang.String-) and each of the other elements to [Double.parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z,-?\d{2,3}\.\d{7},-?\d{2,3}\.\d{7},-?\d{1,2}\.\d/
```

For example, \d{4} means "4 digits", and -* means "0 or more dashes", so should match either postive or negative numbers.

You could also be more generic by using groups of possible characters like this:

```
/[0-9-]{10}[0-9TZ:]{10},[0-9-.,]{26,28}/
```

I.e., any digit or dash for 10 characters, than digits or the letters T or Z or colon for 10 more characters, then a comma, and digits, dash, period, or comma for 26-28 characters. That is not as strict as the regex above, but may be sufficient depending on your requirements.

The above works for javascript and perl, and here is the R version (double escapes):

```
s <- "2014-08-06T21:02:16Z,-33.7939310,151.0553090,-0.8"
grep("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z,-?\\d{2,3}\\.\\d{7},-?\\d{2,3}\\.\\d{7},-?\\d{1,2}\\.\\d", s)
```

Comment: What if the digits are variable? so for the -0.8 in another string it might be 15.0

Comment: I'd suggest using `-?` instead of `-*` when checking for the hyphens, as that will only allow "zero or one hyphens" instead of "zero or more hyphens".

Comment: The \d{2,3} earlier in the regex means "2 or 3 digits".  So similarly, at the end you could use \d{1,2} for 1-2 digits.  I editted answer.

Comment: @bdx yes...that would be more specific and better.  probably doesn't matter so much here, but ? rather than * will keep you out of (potentially a lot of) trouble in other contexts when you know you are looking for exactly 0 or 1 of something.  Edited answer

Comment: Last thing, when I use this I get an invalid escape sequence at the start of the regex how could I fix that?

Comment: Hmm.  What platform/language?  The above works for me as is in both perl and javascript.  If you are in R (which now that I re-read your question I expect is the case since you mention "\\d") you need to double-escape everything.  Change every "\" to "\\".  Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z,-?\d*\.?\d*,\d*\.\d*,-?\d*\.\d*$
```

Try this.See demo.Set flags `m`.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/7